# Women giving birth daily ( Olam Ha-Ba )

Tags: sources-mekorot, olam-haba-world-to-come, children

I have read on an article that in the world to come , every day women will bear children and I want to know if this is true and if so where it says that in the Mishnah.

Answer (score 5):

The source is in a gemara in [Masechta Shabbos 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.30b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בְּדִבְרֵי תוֹרָה מַאי הִיא? — כִּי הָא דְּיָתֵיב רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל וְקָא דָרֵישׁ: **עֲתִידָה אִשָּׁה שֶׁתֵּלֵד בְּכָל יוֹם**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר ״הָרָה וְיוֹלֶדֶת יַחְדָּיו״. לִיגְלֵג עָלָיו אוֹתוֹ תַּלְמִיד, אָמַר: ״אֵין כׇּל חָדָשׁ תַּחַת הַשָּׁמֶשׁ״! אֲמַר לֵיהּ: בֹּא וְאַרְאֶךָּ דּוּגְמָתָן בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה. נְפַק אַחְוִי לֵיהּ תַּרְנְגוֹלֶת.
>
> In matters of Torah, what is the case with regard to which the verse said that one should respond to a fool’s folly? As in the case where Rabban Gamliel was sitting and he interpreted a verse homiletically: **In the future, in the World-to-Come, a woman will give birth every day**, as it says: “The woman with child and her that gives birth together” ([Jeremiah 31:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.31.8?lang=bi)), explaining that birth will occur on the same day as conception. A certain student scoffed at him and said: That cannot be, as it has already been stated: “There is nothing new under the sun” ([Ecclesiastes 1:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.9?lang=bi)). Rabban Gamliel said to him: Come and I will show you an example of this in this world. He took him outside and showed him a chicken that lays eggs every day. (Sefaria translation and notation)

Answer (score 2):

[From Din Online](https://dinonline.org/2021/07/26/about-the-resurrection/):

> The Talmud (Shabbos 30a) writes that there will be a time when a woman
> will conceive and give birth on the same day, without having the
> difficulties of pregnancy and childbirth.
>
> This will be after the sin of Adam is rectified. This is because the
> pains of pregnancy and childbirth are to atone for the sin of Eve,
> however after that is rectified things will return the original way
> that God wanted it to be.
>
> Have no fear. At that point there will be no concern about having
> food, or housing for all of them. Nor will there be any concern of how
> the parents will put them through college.
>
> Best wishes.